# How to detect which video ended when using multiple AVPlayers?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem, avkit

I am playing two videos side by side on screen so I have two instances of AVPlayer. I am detecting end of video playback using notification which is working fine. My selector(playerDidFinishPlaying) is getting called for both videos when they end.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

Now my problem is in the selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), I want to detect for which avplayer it got called? How can I uniquely identify the AVPlayer whose video ended?

Comment: My selector is getting called perfectly fine for both videos when they end. I want to uniquely identify the avplayer for which it got called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another idea. Updated @black_pearl's method

Different notification registration , with different notification methods.

```
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerTwo = AVPlayer()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlay(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishMusic(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerTwo.currentItem)

    }


       @objc func playerDidFinishPlay(_ noti: Notification) {
           if let p = noti.object as? AVPlayerItem, p == player.currentItem {
                print("1")
           }
       }


    @objc func playerDidFinishMusic(_ noti: Notification) {
        if let p = noti.object as? AVPlayerItem, p == playerTwo.currentItem{
            print("2")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

via the object of notification to uniquely identify,

post notification `.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` with object of `player.currentItem`

```
NotificationCenter
    .default
    .addObserver(self, 
                 selector: #selector(self.moviePlayBackFinished(sender:)),
                 name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                 object: player.currentItem)
```

---

The easy way:

The following code works, the drawback is that when one player ends, the notify method will be called twice.

```
    var player = AVPlayer()
    var playerTwo = AVPlayer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlay(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlay(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerTwo.currentItem)

    }


     @objc func playerDidFinishPlay(_ noti: Notification) {
        if let p = noti.object as? AVPlayerItem, p == player.currentItem{
             print("1")
        }

        if let p = noti.object as? AVPlayerItem, p == playerTwo.currentItem{
             print("2")
        }
    }
```

---

**The track state way:**

With Notification, you can see that, there is a player ended.

You need to find the player.

The player must obey two rules, it has began , and it was over.

Use `var hasPlay: (one: Bool, two: Bool)`, to find the player just playing.

Use `isPlaying` to find the player, no longer played.

```
var player = AVPlayer()
var playerTwo = AVPlayer()

var hasPlay: (one: Bool, two: Bool) = (false, false)


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlay), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func beepPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        hasPlay.one = true
        let url = // ...
        player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
        player.play()

    }


    @IBAction func beepPressedTwo(_ sender: UIButton) {
       hasPlay.two = true

       let url = // ...
       playerTwo = AVPlayer(url: url!)
       playerTwo.play()

    }

    @objc func playerDidFinishPlay() {

        if player.isPlaying == false, hasPlay.one == true{
            hasPlay.one = false
            print("1")
        }

        if playerTwo.isPlaying == false, hasPlay.two == true{
            hasPlay.two = false
            print("2")
        }


    }

}




extension AVPlayer {
    var isPlaying: Bool {
        return rate != 0 && error == nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two players. So which object should I pass? player1.currentItem or player2.currentItem?

Answer (score 1):

Updated @dengST30's method one, with some ease.

with two notification registered, any end method will be called twice.

So it needs to add some mutually exclusive.

```
var player = AVPlayer()
var playerTwo = AVPlayer()

var justEnded: (one: Bool, two: Bool) = (false, false)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlay(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlay(_:)), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerTwo.currentItem)
    playButton.tintColor = .systemBlue
}



@objc func playerDidFinishPlay(_ noti: Notification) {
           if let p = noti.object as? AVPlayerItem, p == player.currentItem {

                if justEnded.one == false{
                    print("1")
                }
                justEnded.one.toggle()
           }

           if let p = noti.object as? AVPlayerItem, p == playerTwo.currentItem{
                if justEnded.two == false{
                    print("2")
                }

                justEnded.two.toggle()
           }
       }
```